# Trap mouse in SDL2

Tags: sdl, mouse

When using SDL 1.2 it the way to implement full screen or windowed applications with "no cursor" you did the following:

```
SDL_ShowCursor(SDL_DISABLE);
SDL_WM_GrabInput(SDL_GRAB_ON);
```

See [Trap mouse in SDL](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33519/trap-mouse-in-sdl)

Unfortunately I am unable to get the same behavior with SDL 2.0. I implemented the above as:

```
SDL_Window* window;
// ...
SDL_ShowCursor(SDL_DISABLE);
SDL_SetWindowGrab(window, SDL_TRUE);
```

Am I missing something or do you have to wrap the cursor manually back to the center of the window/screen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is [SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.fcg/SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode). How can I have missed that.